# C++ error: fields must have a constant size

Tags: c++

can someone please give me a hint how to solve the following problem:

```
clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main createLibrary/configuration.cpp createLibrary/growbox.cpp createLibrary/helper.cpp createLibrary/httprequests.cpp main.cpp
In file included from createLibrary/configuration.cpp:2:
In file included from createLibrary/configuration.h:1:
In file included from createLibrary/growbox.h:12:
createLibrary/httprequests.h:13:10: error: fields must have a constant size:
      'variable length array in structure' extension will never be supported
    char device[configuration::maxNameSize];
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I'm including the .h files in the order `configuration.h`, `httprequests.h`. I want all necessary config-parameters to be configured in the `configuration.cpp` file, but I got the displayed error. What am I doing wrong here?

#### configuration.h

```
extern int const maxNameSize;
```

#### configuration.cpp

```
int const configuration::maxNameSize = 30;
```

#### httprequests.h

```
char device[configuration::maxNameSize];
```

#### httprequests.cpp

```
char HTTPREQUESTS::device[configuration::maxNameSize];
```

Comment: Array size must not only be constants, they must be *compile time constants*. A value declared in another compilation unit is not a compile time constant, because obviously the compiler doesn't know what it's value is when compiling httprequests.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `maxNameSize` like this

```
// configuration.h
class configuration
{
public:
    static const int maxNameSize = 30;
    ...
};
```

And no need to define it in configuration.cpp.

Your way doesn't make `maxNamesize` a compile time constant.

**EDIT**, I am assuming that `configuration` is a class. If it's a namespace then do the following instead

```
// configuration.h
namespace configuration
{
    const int maxNamesize = 30;
    ...
}
```

Constants are an exception to the one definition rule, so it's OK to define them in a header file.

Comment: Both of your suggestions violate ODR when included into multiple translation units.

Answer (score 3):

An `extern const int` is not a [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression).

> a variable is usable in constant expressions at a point P if
>
> - the variable is
>
>   - a constexpr variable, or
>   - it is a constant-initialized variable
>   - of reference type or
>   - of const-qualified integral or enumeration type
> - and the definition of the variable is reachable from P
> - and
>
>   - **P is in the same translation unit as the definition of the variable**

(emphasis added)

> I want all necessary config-parameters to be configured in the
>   configuration.cpp file

You are out of luck. The *value* of `maxNameSize` must be visible to it's compile-time users.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong here?

You have defined an array variable with size that is not compile time constant.

Solution: You can either

- Define the variable in the same translation unit where you use it as the size of an array so that it may be compile time constant. Given that the array is in a header, which presumably is included into multiple translation units, the size cannot be defined externally. It has to be either static or inline.
- Or use a dynamic array instead. Simplest way to create dynamic array is to use `std::vector`.